# Understanding perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, move-semantics

As I understand rvalue being passed as an argument into function becomes lvalue,
std::forward returns rvalue if argument was passed as rvalue and lvalue if it was passed as lvalue. Here is my class:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass()
    {
        std::cout << "default";
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass& copy)
    {
        std::cout << "copy";
    }

    MyClass& operator= (const MyClass& right)
    {
        std::cout << "=";
        return *this;
    }

    MyClass& operator= (const MyClass&& right)
    {
        std::cout << "mov =";
        return *this;
    }

    MyClass(MyClass&& mov)
    {
        std::cout << "mov constructor";
    }
};

void foo(MyClass s)
{
    MyClass z = MyClass(std::forward<MyClass>(s));
}

void main()
{
    auto a = MyClass();
    foo(MyClass()); //z is created by move_constructor
    foo(a); //z is created by move_constructor, but I think it must be created using copy constructor
}
```

My question is: why z variable is created using move_constructor in both cases.
I thought it must be moved in first case foo(MyClass()) and copied in 2nd case foo(a). In second case I pass lvalue as argument s, and std::forward must return lvalue, that is then is passed as lvalue reference into MyClass constructor. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Perfect forwarding only works with template code.  You don't have any templates so you aren't forwarding.

Comment: Give this a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward

Comment: You can only (meaningfully) `forward` a forwarding reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are sufficiently confused. The role of forward is **only** important when universal references come into play, and universal reference is something like `T&& t` but **only** when T is a template parameter.

For example, in `void foo(X&& x);` `x` is not a forwarding reference, it is a normal rvalue reference, and forwarding it makes no sense. Rather, you use `std::move` if you want to preserve it's rvalueness, otherwise it becomes an l-value:

```
void foo(X&& x) {
     bar(x); // calls bar with an l-value x, x should be not moved from

     baz(std::move(x)); // calls bar with an r-value x, x is likely moved from after this and probably unusable
}
```

In other words, above function `foo` was specifically crafted to take rvalue references as it's argument, and will not accept anything else. You, as a function writer, defined it's contract in such way.

In contrast, in a context like `template <class T> void foo(T&& t)` `t` is a forwarding reference. Due to reference collapsing rule, it could be an rvalue or an lvalue reference, depending on the valueness of the expression given to the function foo at the call site. In such case, you use

```
template<class T>
void foo(T&& t) {
    // bar is called with value matching the one at the call site                  
    bar(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the argument that you've declared is `MyClass`. Whatever is the expression that initialises the argument is irrelevant in the case of your function - it does not affect the type of the argument.

`MyClass` is not a reference type. `std::forward` converts an lvalue expression of non-reference type to an rvalue. The use of `std::forward` in this context is equivalent to `std::move`.

Note that the argument itself is copy-constructed in the call `foo(a)`.